# Dependency Inversion Principle in Spring-boot maven multi module for a messaging system

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have been trying to figure out a pattern to satisfy the SOLID Dependency Inversion Principle while using Spring-boot in a Maven multi-module project. The goal is to have an abstraction layer between my message provider and consumer. That way I can swap out my message provider easily and keep things loosely coupled.

**ModuleA** -> Spring-boot Kafka Consumer  (should be easily replaceable)

**ModuleB** -> Abstract Message Provider  (should be able to transform messages)

**ModuleC** -> MyMessage Processor  (should be able to use the transformed messages for business logic)

According to the **SOLID** principle:

ModuleC should depend on ModuleB

Module A should depend on ModuleB

Using Spring-boot with dependency injection in a Maven multi-module project complicates this for me.

```
In ModuleA I receive messages using Apache Kafka libraries, all contained in its own maven module.

In ModuleB I expose a Java LinkedBlockingQueue that ModuleA can fill with messages as they come in.

It's here that I transform the message. To make the messages available to ModuleC I expose an 
Observable Class as a Spring @Component.

In ModuleC I Inject the ModuleB Component and add an Observer to detect new messages.
```

This all works and here is the [code](https://github.com/hambone01/dependency-inversion-spring-boot) for all to see.

Is this just WRONG. Is there a correct Spring way to do this? Though it works, something just smells wrong about it, to me.

Thanks you.

Comment: "Smells wrong" is far too vague. What is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is a common one, trying to abstract functionality away from a specific implementation (kafka) when using annotations and maven. My question is an attempt to get feedback on a better solution.